# Invoke Web Request is not working in Powershell when running the job from Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, email, attachment

I have written a script to send an email with multiple attachments and URL details as in the mail, but when I run that script using the task scheduler job the URL content is not displaying in the mail, but the same thing when I debug and normally run the script I am getting the URL content in the mail.

Can anyone have any idea on how to get the URL contained in the mail when we schedule the Job task scheduler?

**Code**

```
###############Run thebatch file to Copy all the Reports####################
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\scripts\CMS_Prod_Hourly_HC\AllReportFiles.bat"

##############Sleep For 10 Seconds to Copy all the reports#################
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

$Date = get-date #Get Current System date and time

$NewDocCreation = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://facebook.com'
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
$WorkFlowGeneration = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://google.com'
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
$DocAdminJobStatus = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://yahoo.com' 

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

$CMS = $NewDocCreation.Content + $WorkFlowGeneration.Content + $DocAdminJobStatus.Content

Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
#HTML Template
$EmailBody = @"

 <table style="width: 68%" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #008080;">
 <tr>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#008080" style="text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: medium; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #008080;"> 
        <h3> Global Audit Technology - CMS AMS (App0036) <h3 />
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px">
    <td style="border: 1px solid #008080; text-align: center; width: 150px; height: 20px">Job Name</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #008080; text-align: center; height: 20px; width: 233px;">XYZ</td>
 </tr>
  <tr style="height: 39px; border: 1px solid #008080">
  <td style="border: 1px solid #008080; text-align: center; width: 150px; height: 20px">Job HostName</td>
 <td style="border: 1px solid #008080; text-align: center; height: 20px; width: 233px;">ABC.com</td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="height: 39px; border: 1px solid #008080">
  <td style="border: 1px solid #008080; text-align: center; width: 150px; height: 20px">Team Name</td>
 <td style="border: 1px solid #008080; text-align: center; height: 20px; width: 233px;">Audit</td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="height: 39px; border: 1px solid #008080">
  <td style="border: 1px solid #008080; text-align: center; width: 150px; height: 20px">Team DL</td>
 <td style="border: 1px solid #008080; text-align: center; height: 20px; width: 233px;">abc.com</td>
 </tr>
</table>
"@
  
############################ Define other variables ##########################
$hash = @{
    from        = "abc.com"
    to          = "xyz.com"
    subject     = "Health checks - $Date"
    smtpserver  = "smpt.com"
    port        = "25"
    attachments = (get-childitem "C:\scripts\CMS_Prod_Hourly_HC\AllReportFiles").fullname
    body        =  "<font face='calibri' color='black' size='+1'><h4>Please review the attached reports</h4></font>" + 
    $EmailBody + "<br/>" + $CMS + "<br/><br/><font face='calibri' color='grey' size='-1'><i>PS: This is an autogenerated email, please do not reply to this email.</i></font>"
    BodyAsHtml  = $true
 }
#########################Send Email with All Health Check Reports###############
Send-MailMessage @hash

##############Sleep For 10 Seconds and Delete the Report files#################
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

#######################Clean up the Reports Folder#############################
Remove-Item C:\scripts\CMS_Prod_Hourly_HC\AllReportFiles\* -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: What user is running the task?

Comment: Admin user, i am running this account with one of our Service account